# How to take screenshot of indicator menus?

Tags: indicator, screenshot

If I hover over to the setting menu or any of the indicator menus, `Prnt Scrn`button won't work.

If I want to take the snapshot of these menus, how do I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the Screenshot application included with 12.04

Open the Dash and type **screenshot**

[image]

With this application you can set a delay, by adjusting the value in the "Grab after a delay of" box, before it will automatically take a screenshot allowing you to open the menu you want a picture of.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Shutter-Indicator](http://shutter-project.org)

**A less mechanical method to print a pop-up menu.**  This software have a *dedicated option* to do that.

I recommend you this software with more options that facilitates your work. Also, with this app you can capture:

- A window
- A menu
- A pop up
- A website
- The whole desktop, a part of this one, and more!

This has a *daemon* to take screen-shots more quickly and easily:
[image: indicator]

Also have a built-in image editor to customize the photo just taken.

By default it has 3 seconds of delay, to disable go to Edit then Preferences and set the delay value to 0.

You can install it from the [Software-Center](http://apps.ubuntu.com) or download all versions and source from [their website](http://shutter-project.org).

Comment: Is there a method for taking screenshot of a menu without any delay?

Comment: There is, I just added it.

Answer (score -3):

Install the application Sutter, then select the area you want to take the screenshot of and apply the delay in which you will be able to reach that indicator, like I did for my [blog](http://mknadeem.blogspot.in/2011/11/ubuntu-1110-explored.html)