# How do I take a screenshot of the alt-tab menu?

Tags: 12.04, screenshot

In Ubuntu 12.04, when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, the following menu comes up:

```
(TODO: take screenshot of alt-tab menu)
```

But while I have the alt-tab menu up, when I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, and therefore <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, it takes a screenshot of the active window.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/126787/how-to-take-screenshot-of-indicator-menus

Comment: Just tested, with 3-second delay, on **12.04**.  Works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this trouble myself, but there's a sneaky workaround.

Open "Screenshot" from the Dash and set a timer before the shot, about 5 or so seconds. Then, click "Take Screenshot" and hold Alt+Tab. You should get a screenshot.

Comment: Works well, I generally use 3-second delay.