# Cannot take a screenshot when clicking on top-right system tray icon

Tags: 12.10, screenshot, system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take screenshot of indicator menus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126787/how-to-take-screenshot-of-indicator-menus)

When I say top-right icon is the: wifi, volume, clock, system gear... When one of them showing the menu, I cannot take a screenshot!
My Ubuntu is 12.10 32bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take screenshot of indicator menus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126787/how-to-take-screenshot-of-indicator-menus) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/15639/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-desktop-with-app-menu-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'Screenshot' to take a screenshot of the entire screen but with a 10-second delay. During the delay, click the item of interest so the menu appears. The resulting screenshot will include the menu and pointer. I generally rename the .png to something meaningful; not just Screenshot...blah.png. I then open the .png in GIMP and crop to the area of interest.[image: NM_icon.png]