# How do I screenshot Wifi Network Authentication Required window's Authentication menu? (apparent bug; Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, networking, display, clipboard, screenshot

My 'Prt Sc / Sys Rq' key is apparently disabled whenever I have the Wifi Network Authentication Required window's Authentication drop-up menu open, but it appears to work otherwise. Is this a bug or a 'security feature'? It looks to me to be a bug. What causes this problem and how do we fix it?

(sony vaio computer with Japanese keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use the graphical user interface

You can launch the Screenshot app from Ubuntu Dash:

[image]

Type *screenshot* in the dash and you will see an icon with a camera. You can drag the icon to the launcher for easy access.

[image]

When you click on the camera icon, the screenshot app will launch:

[image]

Then you can take the screenshot of the whole screen, the active window or just a part of the screen. Once you click the *Take Screenshot* button at the bottom, you will get the option to save the screenshot or copy it to the clipboard.

By the way, bugs are off-topic in this site. If you found a bug, you may want to [file a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Hope this helps

Comment: Alt+PrtSc does nothing when that menu is active; otherwise, it only takes a screenshot. Rather than open some program, Alt+PrtSc only takes a screenshot of the built-in monitor, rather than all monitors. So it seems to me I should not accept this answer, since some of the information is incorrect. By the way, I wasn't sure if it was a bug or deliberate design. When not sure, isn't it better to ask? Thank you for the effort and showing me how to report bugs.

Comment: Yes, your method works. It appears to be using the graphical interface equivalent to the terminal command I posted as an answer previously (except with options "-w -d 4" instead of "-d 10"). Your answer is prettier, and perhaps more useful to the novice, but my answer literally solved my problem ... but my asked question still hasn't been answered about what prevents the screenshot, but perhaps I should accept your answer since you suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: user68186, that is not the condition of the bug or security feature, whichever it is. As I said, "with the Wifi Network Authentication Required window's Authentication drop-up menu open". You must go into the WiFi settings, go to the WiFi Security tab, and open the PEAP etc drop-down menu and then try to take the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Although not resolving the key functionality problem, one workaround is to execute the following command in the Terminal to take a screenshot after 10 seconds:

```
gnome-screenshot -d 10
```

(or search 'screenshot' in the Launcher (top left button) to open the graphical user interface to accomplish the same task).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the terminal then `scrot -cd10` should get the job done.

`scrot` can be installed via the command `sudo apt-get install scrot`

Comment: I typed 'man scrot' to learn about this command in the Terminal, but the output was 'No manual entry for scrot'. Searching online, am I correct in understanding that it is a separate package I would need to install? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Scrot That page was last edited six years ago, and apparently abandoned, so I am hesitant to try installing this package ... Checking a related answer, it appears 'gnome-screenshot' is now the go-to package: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126787/how-to-take-screenshot-of-indicator-menus?rq=1 Thank you for helping me find this answer!

Comment: yes, you would have to install the scrot package. `sudo apt-get install scrot`. editing to include that step